# How to format a managed metadata column based on the term?

Tags: sharepoint-online, managed-metadata, json-formatting, guid

I have a column with managed metadata from the local term store. I want to format each term in a different color, based on the value of the term.

I am very novice so I started tried with the JSON formatting examples in https://github.com/pnp/List-Formatting/tree/master/column-samples/managed-metadata-tag-icon.

I was able to introduce the "equality" operator where needed, but I found out that it does succeeds only when I apply it to the label.

For example, this doesn't work:

```
{
  "operator": "==",
  "operands": [
    "@currentField",
    "label|GUID"
  ]
}
```

but this one does:

```
{
  "operator": "==",
  "operands": [
    "=toString(@currentField)",
    "label"
  ]
}
```

But the label could change in the future, so I think it is better to use only the GUID for the comparison.

I couldn't find any help in https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/formatting-syntax-reference

How to compare the term using the GUID, not based on the label?